# R syntax problems -- part 2 redux

Tags: r

All I have is a csv file which has rows of monthly dates and columns that are numerical whole number counts.

All I want to do is have the user select a category e.g. number of chats and have it make a plot of the time series.

The uiOutput simply won't work regardless of where I put it. I keep getting errors like

> object server not found, object UI not found Error in output$regionSel = renderUI(selectInput("region", "Type of Questions:",  : 
>     object 'output' not found

I have spent four days on this and am about to give up as this seems not a solvable problem even though I see lots of examples of much more complex interactions. I have read tutorials and watched youtube videos on this endlessly with no positive effect.

Is this because I am using dates and R has a problem with dates?

```
UI
# Rely on the 'WorldPhones' dataset in the datasets
# package (which generally comes preloaded).
library(datasets)
library(ggplot2)
library(readr)

oboler_data <- read_csv(file = "C:/Users/12083/Desktop/ref.csv")
rdate <- as.Date(oboler_data$DATE,"%m/%d/%y")
# Use a fluid Bootstrap layout
fluidPage(    

    # Give the page a title
    titlePanel("Teephones by region"),

    # Generate a row with a sidebar
    sidebarLayout(      




        # Define the sidebar with one input
        sidebarPanel(

            uiOutput("regionSel")



            #selectInput("region", "Region:", 
            # choices=colnames(oboler_data)),


            # ),

            # Create a spot for the barplot
            mainPanel(
                plotOutput("myPlot")  
            )

            #)
            #)

            server
# Rely on the 'WorldPhones' dataset in the datasets
# package (which generally comes preloaded).
library(datasets)
library(ggplot2)
oboler_data <- read_csv(file = "C:/Users/12083/Desktop/ref.csv")
rdate <- as.Date(oboler_data$DATE,"%m/%d/%y")
# Define a server for the Shiny app
function(input, output) {

    output$regionSel = renderUI(selectInput("region", "Type of Questions:",
                                            choices=colnames(oboler_data)))
    # Fill in the spot we created for a plot
    output$myPlot = renderPlot({


        # Render a barplot
        ggplot(data = oboler_data, aes_string(x = "rdate", y = input$regionSel)) +
            geom_point() +
            labs(x = "Date",
                 y = "Total Transactions",
                 title = "Library Data",
                 subtitle = "July 2020-June 2021") 
    })
```

Comment: please provide a reprex, there are multiple datasets with datetimes in r

Comment: To blindly solve your issue, the name of your selector is region not regionSel

Comment: also why are you rendering the regionSel server side, this is too complicated for your example move it into de ui and just expose the selector itself (region), that way you won't get confused on what is actually the selector

Comment: ok there is lot wrong with this example, you need a ui function, a server function a a run app function, have you read the tutorial https://shiny.rstudio.com/tutorial/?

Comment: It doesn't help. He talks about reactive elements which is fine and then wanders off into using r coding HTML. No explanation of how to use pulldown menus, csv, etc and integrate the UI with the server

Comment: I don't mean just the video I mean the concept, you can read the first three chapters at least, another resources would be mastering shiny by Hadley Wickham

Comment: I get the concept fine -- the idea that you are making a reactive expression like putting a number in one excel cell and a formula that works on it in another and changing one makes the other do something makes perfect sense. I just cannot get the syntax right so that this is what is happening. I can't seem to get the UI output in the UI to take whatever is chosen and send it to the server.  Now when I run this I see code and output completely unrelated to the app .

Comment: I just posted my latest attempt if anyone cares to look.  keeps saying object output not found while producing output in the viewer from some other app I was working with that has zero to do with this project and is closed.  I don't get something about uiOutput and how it handles choices using the columns in a csv fielduiOutput("regionSel"),
               selectInput("regionSel", "Type of Questions:", 
               choices=colnames(oboler_data)),

Answer (score 1):

You have left out the assignment of the `ui` and `server` functions to the objects `ui` and `server`. So write `ui <- FluidPage()` and `server <- function(input, output)` instead  `FluidPage()` and `function(input, output)`. This explains the first two error codes. Finally, in `aes_string(x = "rdate", y = input$regionSel)` I think that you need to refer to `input$region`: this is the `id` of the `selectInput` widget. `regionSel` is the id related to the `uiOutput`. When using dynamic ui you need to keep these id's apart.

Once you fix that things will work. Here's a simple shiny application that does what you are after.

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)
library(ggplot2)

data <- tibble(
  DATE = seq.Date(from = as.Date("2020/01/01"), to = as.Date("2020/06/19"), by = "day"),
  VAR1 = seq(1, 171, 1) + round(runif(n = 171, min = 0, max = 100), 0),
  VAR2 = seq(1, 171, 1) + round(runif(n = 171, min = 0, max = 100), 0),
  VAR3 = seq(1, 171, 1) + round(runif(n = 171, min = 0, max = 100), 0),
  VAR4 = seq(1, 171, 1) + round(runif(n = 171, min = 0, max = 100), 0),
  VAR5 = seq(1, 171, 1) + round(runif(n = 171, min = 0, max = 100), 0)
)

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage(

  # Application title
  titlePanel("Library Statistics"),

  # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins 
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      uiOutput("select")
      ),
    # Show a plot of the generated distribution
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("distPlot")
    )
  )
)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {

  output$select <- renderUI(
    selectInput(inputId = "select_question",
                label = "Type of question",
                choices = data %>% select(-DATE) %>% colnames(.)
  ))

  output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
    req(input$select_question)
    var <- input$select_question
    ggplot(data = data, aes_string(x = "DATE", y = var)) +
      geom_point() +
      labs(x = "Date",
           y = "Total Transactions",
           title = "Library Data",
           subtitle = "July 2020-June 2021") 
  })
}
```